# How to disable cache on pages served by Hunchentoot?

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I am trying to disable Hunchentoot's caching of pages, to streamline web development on local host.

As I understand, the function [no-cache](http://edicl.github.io/hunchentoot/#no-cache) is meant to be used, but I'm unsure how to incorporate this. I currently have the following code that evaluates without error, however this is relates to dynamically served content, so I am unable to check whether the no-cache function is correct. Also I have no idea how to add handler functions to handlers.

```
(hunchentoot:define-easy-handler
  (test-fn :uri "/test.html") (name)
  (setf (hunchentoot:content-type*) "text/plain")
  (hunchentoot:no-cache)
  (format nil "Hey~@[ ~A~]!" name))
```

I'm unable to find a way to add no-cache to static dispatch and handlers, such as the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285115/how-to-tell-hunchentoot-where-to-find-static-web-pages-to-serve/8285711):

```
(push (hunchentoot:create-static-file-dispatcher-and-handler
        "/url.html" "/path/to/www_/actual-page.html")
  hunchentoot:*dispatch-table*)
```

The above example bypasses caching because I believe it is dynamically serving the page.

Below is my server configuration. Static pages are being cached currently. I would like to understand the Hunchentoot mechanism to disable cache for all resources but also disabling for specified resources (leaving it on for other resources).

```
(defvar *ssg-web-server* (hunchentoot:start 
              (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor 
                     :address "127.0.0.1" 
                     :port 4242 
                     :document-root #p"/path/to/www_/"
                     :persistent-connections-p t
                     :read-timeout 3.0 
                     :write-timeout 3.0
                     :access-log-destination nil
                     :message-log-destination nil)))
```

Comment: To check if `no-cache` takes effect, check the response headers in the browser dev tools? `cache-control` is set to "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" by Hunchentoot, `expires`, `pragma` and `last-modified` are set too.

Answer (score 1):

`create-static-file-dispatcher-and-handler` accepts a callback:

> CALLBACK is run just before sending the file, and can be used
> to set headers or check authorization;
> arguments are the filename and the (guessed) content-type.

I suppose you can write:

```
(defun no-cache-static-callback (file content-type)
  (declare (ignore file content-type))
  (no-cache))
```

And you would pass this function as follows, namely with a NIL content-type and the callback function:

```
(create-static-file-dispatcher-and-handler
  "/url.html" 
  "/path/to/www_/actual-page.html" 
  nil
  #'no-cache-static-callback)
```

Comment: Thanks @coredump. I got a 500 Server Error when using `#'no-cache-static-callback` into `create-static-file-dispatcher-and-handler`. My code for the previous function was `(defun no-cache-static-callback (file content-type) (declare (ignore file content-type) (Hunchentoot:no-cache) `  -----> The code evaluates correctly so I will look into what the error is..